# redux-toolkit createAction() type definition in typescript

Tags: typescript, generics, redux, redux-toolkit

I am exploring `redux-toolkit` library recently but facing difficulty about type declaration of the `createAction` function as shown below.

`createAction` returns a PayloadActionCreator which has a generic of `<ReturnType<PA>['payload'], T, PA>`. However, what does it mean by `ReturnType<PA>['payload']`?

```
export declare function createAction<PA extends PrepareAction<any>, T extends string = string>(type: T, prepareAction: PA): PayloadActionCreator<ReturnType<PA>['payload'], T, PA>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ReturnType<PA>['payload']` means the `payload` property of the object returned by the `prepare` function - as this is the signature for the `prepare` notation.

However, this should not concern you. The usual usage is `const actionCreator = createAction<PayloadType>('some/action/type')`.

The alternative notation would be the prepare notation, in the form `createAction('some/action/type', (payload: string) => ({ payload, meta: {something: "foo"}})`.

In general, please refer to [the API documentation](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createAction) that has almost all usage examples in TypeScript.
You really should not write more types than are present there. (And yes, that's not a lot of types, that's pretty much the point ;) )

Comment: Thank you. I think I have miss the point that the generic type for ```ReturnType``` should be a function. 

Definitely I am not gonna change the type definition :))) Just wanna train up the ability of reading the function definition. I think this can help me to use the function better.